# Import.io - REGEX get table td value from th

Tags: php, html, regex, web-scraping

i need help.
I'am using import.io and want to scrape table data using regex and want to get value from some column, here is the code

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td class='label'>No. Urut</td>
      <td class='titikdua'>:</td>
      <td>201</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class='label'>Kode</td>
      <td class='titikdua'>:</td>
      <td>DF 045</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class='label'>Warna</td>
      <td class='titikdua'>:</td>
      <td>HITAM</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class='label'>Bahan</td>
      <td class='titikdua'>:</td>
      <td>KULIT</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class='label'>Berat</td>
      <td class='titikdua'>:</td>
      <td>0 gr</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class='label'>Info</td>
      <td class='titikdua'>:</td>
      <td>SOL : FIBER</td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id='fr-stok'>
<table id='t01'>
   <tr>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Stok</th>
      <th>Pesanan</th>
      <th>Last Update</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>05 Oct 17, 15:39:53</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>08 Oct 17, 12:24:28</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>07 Oct 17, 14:22:07</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>04 Oct 17, 15:52:41</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

and i want to get **size** value and convert it to **38,39,40,41,42,43** how i can do it with regex

Comment: sory, i mean from 38-43, i have been edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`<tr>\s*<td>\s*\K\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/WWca6v/1/)

```
<tr> matches the characters <tr> literally (case sensitive)
\s*
matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
<td> matches the characters <td> literally (case sensitive)
\s*
matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\K resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
\d+
matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, how about using xpath ? this html     <table id='t01'><tr><th>Size</th><th>Stok</th><th>Pesanan</th><th>Last Update</th></tr><tr><td>36</td><td>4</td><td>0</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>37</td><td>6</td><td>0</td><td>09 Oct 17, 16:20:34</td></tr><tr><td>38</td><td>5</td><td>0</td><td>08 Oct 17, 15:41:15</td></tr><tr><td>39</td><td>6</td><td>0</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>40</td><td>7</td><td>0</td><td>04 Oct 17, 17:27:02</td></tr></table>